# Analytic function is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

I looked around the site and  I couldn't seem to find a similar question. But, I came across this question:

Let $f$ be analytic from the unit disc to the complex plane with the property that $|f(z)|\leq |f(z^2)|$ for all $z \in D.$ Show $f(z)$ is constant.

I did a similar problem where we assume we $f(z)$ is an entire map and that  was straight forward since we could write $f(z) = c f(z^2),$and play around with the taylor coefficients. But now, I don't have any intuition for this problem. I want to use the maximum modulus theorem  but I can't apply it, since we are not continuous  on the closure. I also tried defining a few functions, such as the  difference of the two $f(z)-f(z^2),$ but I seem to be coming up short in either case. Am I missing something? Is there some trick I don't see?

Comment: Use maximum modulus theorem on $|z|\leq r$ for $r<1$

Comment: see as well : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2739812

Answer (score 2):

Following @RodrigoDias, let $r <1$ and consider the restriction of $f$ to $B(0;r)$. If $f$ is non-constant on $B(0;r)$, then there exists $z_0 \in \partial B(0;r)$ such that $z \in B(0;r) \implies |f(z)| \leq |f(z_0)|$. But since $|z_0^2|<|z_0|$,$z_0^2 \in B(0;r)$ and by hypothesis, $|f(z_0)| \leq |f(z_0^2)|$. This is a contradicts the maximum modulus principle. Therefore, $f$ must be constant.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $|f|$ has a maximum in $z=0$. In fact, for $|z|<1$, we have
$$|f(z)|\leq|f(z^2)|\leq|f(z^4)|\leq|f(z^8)|\leq\dots \leq\left|f\left(z^{2^n}\right)\right|\to |f(0)| \text{ for }n \to +\infty$$
where all the inequalities are applications of the given property, and the convergence at the end uses the fact that $|z|<1$, thus $z^{2^n}\to 0$.

If $f$ wasn't constant, it wouldn't have a maximum (by the maximum principle).