# If $ |f(z^{2})|\leq|f(z)| $ and $ f $ is entire, then is $ f $ constant?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Assume $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C} $ entire function, and assume $ f $ satisfies $ |f(z^{2})|\leq|f(z)| $

How can I prove that $ f $ is a constant?

I have tried something but not sure about my way. I'll share my attempt any way:

Let $ \overline{D(0,R^2)} $ be a closed disk with $R^2>1 $. Then by the maximum modulus theorem, $ f $ accepts its maximum on $ C(0,R^2) $, i.e. on some point $ R^{2}e^{i\theta} $. But then we have $ |f(R^{2}e^{i\theta})|\leq f(Re^{i\frac{\theta}{2}})| $ So $ f $ actually assumes its maximum in an inner point of $ \overline{D(0,R^{2})} $, and thus $ f $ is constant in the closed disk, and by the uniqueness theorem, in the whole plane.

I feel like something's wrong with the proof. Any clarifications would be helpful.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Isnt the maximum modulus states that if $f $ attains a maximum in an inner point it has to be constant in this disk?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2739795/show-that-if-f-is-entire-and-forall-z-in-mathbbc-fz2-leq-fz?noredirect=1

Comment: If $f$ is bounded and entire then it is constant. Are you allowed to use this fact?

Comment: @Luke Collins Yes. But im more intrested in understanding whats the problem with my suggetsted proof

Comment: Your proof looks good, it is essentially what is said here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2739812/42969

Comment: @MartinR Thank you Martin. I wanted to make sure that the details as I wrote them are fine. What bothered me is that basically what I said is that given $z_0$ where $f $ assumes its maximum, $f(\sqrt{z_0})$ is bigger. And we cannot define $\sqrt(z_0)$ on the disk